# Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop: unable to ping to localhost:7001

Tags: intellij-idea, weblogic12c

I am trying to run my weblogic from Intellij. I am getting the error:

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping to server at localhost:7001.

In addition to this error, I also see the following error in my Intellij terminal and when I try to run the startWeblogic.cmd:

> The syntax of the command is correct.

The server was working just fine when I tried running another project on the same server. The other project gave this error first and now it's showing up on this project. I did not have the weblogic server running on both of them at the same time. I have also tried deleting the java.exe processes on my computer since that has fixed the unable to ping in the past, but not this time.

**Edit:** I have just tried to run my Weblogic's config.cmd in order to build a new local host, but the cmd line gives me the "syntax is incorrect" just for trying to start up the config.cmd. So, I think this issue is rooted in my Weblogic somehow.

**Edit**: I tried reinstalling a fresh Weblogic 12 and it still gave me "the syntax is incorrect" when I tried running the config.cmd.

Comment: Try restarting the PC. Such issues usually happens when the socket is already used by another process (e.g. the same server is already running on machine) or the socket on 7001 port is not opened in the first place.

Comment: I have tried restarting my computer at least a few times during the course of trying to solve the issue (as that is usually the first thing I try) and this issue has spread over the course of a few days and I shut my computer down every evening. So, I don't think this issue will be resolved by turning it off an don again sadly.

Comment: help me i have same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If you go to Help > Show Log in Finder, and open up `idea.log` you may see the root cause of the problem.

```
2021-06-24 12:18:42,010 [  16549]   WARN - ntellij.ui.tree.AsyncTreeModel - invalid node: WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0 
2021-06-24 12:18:43,589 [  18128]   INFO - xecution.runners.ExecutionUtil - Error running 'WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0':<br>No JDK specified 
com.intellij.execution.CantRunException: No JDK specified
```

As a result, I went into File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project. I noticed there was `<No SDK>`. I changed it to a Java SDK on my computer. I then restarted IntelliJ.

Note I did find that it was still holding onto port 7001 even after this. I used

```
lsof -i tcp:7001
```

to discover the offending process and killed it. I then restarted IntelliJ and was able to start WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with the WildFly server so I changed the configuration and made it run on Tomcat. and it worked for me.